# How to show for times propotions statistical significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I can compare 1 success out of 25 attempts vs. 2 successes out of 25 attempts, but with a proportion of time, it seems more complicated to me. Let me explain. I want to compare two groups, one where there is 1 success out of 25 observations, the other where there are 2 successes out of 26 observations.

In my case these proportions to units ("observations") are replaced by time. For example, George is able to breathe rapidly 25 minutes per hour normally when told a given medication he can breathe rapidly 22 minutes per hour.

I want to know if these two proposals are statistically different.

How to show it?

I would like to point out that I can completely replace the minutes with seconds, which would artificially increase the power of the proportion test (x²) (we can artificially increase the power of the statistical test by replacing 1h with 3600 seconds).

Comment: Do you have a measure of variation for each of these values (before/after treatment)? If so, this could be a simple T-test to see if the difference in values is statistically significant